# How to list files in oracle backupset

Tags: backup, rman

I've backupset created with RMAN, and I want to see what this set contains. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "List Backup", or perhaps "list backup summary"

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/rcmreprt.htm#BRADV89586

and

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10643/rcmsynta027.htm#RCMRF132